# Kali Bootable USB - No live options

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, bootable

I have downloaded kali linux iso 64-bit version 2020.1 (kali-linux-2020.1-installer-amd64.iso) and I followed the instructions (https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-install/) to make a bootable USB using balenaEtcher. But when BIOS boot the USB, in the Kali menu there are no Live options.

The Menu displays the following options:

- Install
- Graphical Install
- Advanced Options
- Accessible dark contrast installer menu
- Help
- Install with speech synthesis

I repeated the procedure but the problem remains.

---

Technical Info: Turbo-X 64 GB USB, Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  `kali-linux-2020.1-installer-amd64.iso` is used to install the system, it doesn't provide a live session.

You need to download the [Kali Linux 64-Bit (Live)](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) iso : `kali-linux-2020.1-live-amd64.iso`.

Comment: This is deceptively annoying. IIRC they used to be packed together ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same option. I downloaded the live version and it didn't have it so I tried with a normal installer iso and it doesn't have it either. There is no live option in either of them meaning the live iso also cannot install because the vital live option is not available in the iso that was packaged in dd format.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421441)